# How do I publish data from the server and listen for changes on the client in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I've figured out that Meteor (as in http://meteor.com) is using SockJS under the hood.

I have some server-side code that periodically check what song is playing in iTunes and I want to publish the track info to the client side.

I've looked at Meteors docs, and Meteor.publish/Meteor.subscribe seem to specifically deal with Meteor.Collections. I just want to pass through arbitrary data, like strings or JSON.

Is there anyway I can do simple pub/sub in Meteor like Socket.IO or Faye?

Comment: I looked for similar arbitrary behavior myself and found nothing, hopefully someone else will chime in. FWIW, I ended up making a collection called 'alerts' and an observe handler that does something special when new alerts get pushed to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can publish arbitrary data.  It doesn't have to come from a Meteor.Collection.

See http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish for a starting point.  You'll want to write a publish function on the server which calls `Meteor.setInterval` to set up a periodic check, and then uses `this.set`, `this.unset`, and `this.flush` to push individual attributes to each client.

Comment: Yea I did look into that, but I couldn't figure out how to retrieve this data on the client via Meteor.subscribe. Any clues?

Comment: Just call `Meteor.subscribe('name')` on the client.  It'll populate a `Meteor.Collection` with the name that your publish function uses when calling `set`.

Comment: So I finally figured out what was wrong... I kept getting errors trying to publish. I looked into the source code and `this.set` only expects 3 arguments (the last being an object literal). Not 4 as stated in the docs :)

Comment: I just opened my app up on my iPad and it looks like it only publishes to the last client to load the app?

Comment: re iPad: that doesn't seem right.  each new client will invoke your publish function on the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10945/discussion-between-cobby-and-debergalis)